# How can I solve python openssl load_cert_chain function error?

Tags: python, openssl, tornado

I'm setting up a new server using Pytoh, tornado.
I'm going to set HTTPS.
But when server loads server certificate files, load_cert_chain function generates an error.
I purchased those certificate files from GoDaddy and it was okay on Apache Server before.
So certificate file and key file match and ca file is also okay.

python version: 3.7.4
tornado version : 4.5.2
openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019

```
ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain("../server.crt", "../server.key")
ssl_ctx.load_verify_locations("../ca.crt")
ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
https_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options=ssl_ctx)
```

This is error message.
    ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain("../server.crt", "../server.key")
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3854)

Comment: there are different formats for certs, make sure you provide a matching format

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Yes. I already confirmed about that via https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html.

Comment: well ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain obviously expects a fullchain cert but you provide a cert with a cert_key
you should research a bit about cert chains :)

Comment: Thank you. So you mean I should get full chain cert file from those and use it for parameter?

Comment: would seem logically to me

Comment: Could you explain me in detail? How can I get full chain cert file from those cert files?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I use NginX server to host python server with digital signed certificates.